# How to Remove Default Property Values from Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webapi

In a Class i have set of properties and i will be able to assign the values for some properties and some properties has default values. Now My case i want to remove those default value properties while returning the object response.

Example :

```
Public class Root {
public int intValue{get;set;}
public string strName{get;set;}
public string imgUrl{get;set}
public DateTime dtmCreated{get;set;}
public DateTime dtmExpiry{get;set;}
}
```

From above when i retrieve response i am seeing the imgurl as null & expiry date as default. i dont want to show those for some cases. how can i remove those properties from object while showing api response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` and `DateTime` can't "not have values".  But their nullable counterparts can.  If you want the properties to allow null values, make them nullable.  For example:

```
public int? intValue { get; set; }
```